# How to implement save completion in 'old' Core Data?

Tags: java, android, ios, swift, core-data

With recent version of `Core Data`saving a worker context is like this:

```
open class func upsertClient(completionOnMain: @escaping () -> ()) {

    let contextTemporary = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
    contextTemporary.parent = context

    contextTemporary.perform {

        try! contextTemporary.save()

        context.perform {

            try! context.save()

            completionOnMain()
        }
    }
}
```

Piece of cake.

But how to do if I need use `registerListener` and `onPostSave` event?

I created global completion closure, and executing and clearing it in `onPostSave`. But because it is written from two different threads, sometimes completion is executed two times. Code below is JAVA. Using old `Core Data` implemented for Android called `nexus-data`, don't worry about it, it is just like in iOS. Looking for a pseudo code solution.

```
public static void upsertClient(final Runnable completionRunnable) {

    saveCompletionHandler = completionHandler;
    saveCompletionRunnable = completionRunnable;
    contextWorker.save();
}

ObjectContextNotifier.registerListener(new ObjectContextNotifier.DefaultObjectContextListener() {
    @Override public void onPostSave(ObjectContext c, ChangedObjectsSet changedObjects) {
        // ensure that the notification we just got is not from our own context, and that it's from a context using a
        // persistence store that our context is also using.
        if (c != context && c.getPersistentStoreCoordinator() == context.getPersistentStoreCoordinator()) {

            // do saving
        }

        saveCompletionRunnable = null;
        saveCompletionHandler = null;
    }
});
```

Comment: What are `registerListener` and `onPostSave`? They're not part of Core Data.

Comment: There is an Android implementation of Core Data. An ethusiast iOS developer made it. Naming convention and approach is like in iOS! It contains basic functionality of Core Data. An ORM for Android. https://github.com/dkharrat/NexusData I really like it, I just need 'downgrade' things to get to work. Need to undersrand how old time Core Data in iOS worked, before patent-child context.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the NexusData developer added or changed some things to deal with (or maybe to best make use of) platform differences.

From what I can tell, `registerListener` and `onPostSave` correspond to the iOS `NSManagedObjectContextDidSave` notification. Use `NotificationCenter` to observe that notification. Any time a managed object context saves changes, the observer code will be called. In Swift the merge method is `mergeChanges(fromContextDidSave:)`. `NSManagedObjectContext` posts some other notifications that might also be useful.